# Many FileStream's attached to one file

Tags: c#

Like in title:

```
FileStream fs  = new FileStream ("test.mkv", FileMode.Open);
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream ("test.mkv", FileMode.Open);
```

It throw an error: The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.

But why, if it is opened for read only (?). If not, how to open file as read only?

Comment: The default FileShare for those constructor calls is FileShare.Read.  The default FileAccess is FileAccess.ReadWrite.  First one got write access, second one *denied* FileShare.Write.  Second one loses, the first one already got write access.  Spell out what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that you're opening it read only and that you're sharing it.

```
var fs1 = new FileStream("test.mkv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
var fs2 = new FileStream("test.mkv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```